# Perl - Parse text file with tags for data dump into new text file

Tags: perl, parsing, text, tabs, tags

I was given data in a .txt file that I need to format into something I can upload into a database. The text is anchored with  whatever . Depending on the tag the data needs to be dumped into a specific txt files and tab delimited. I've done very little Perl in my life, but I know Perl can handle this type of application easily, I'm just lost on where to start. Outside of Java, SQL, and R I'm useless. Here is an example of a single entry I have close to 1,000 of these to deal with):

```xml
<PaperTitle>True incidence of all complications following immediate and delayed breast reconstruction.</PaperTitle>
<Abstract>BACKGROUND: Improved self-image and psychological well-being after breast reconstruction are well documented. To determine methods that optimized results with minimal morbidity, the authors examined their results and complications based on reconstruction method and timing. METHODS: The authors reviewed all breast reconstructions after mastectomy for breast cancer performed under the supervision of a single surgeon over a 6-year period at a tertiary referral center. Reconstruction method and timing, patient characteristics, and complication rates were reviewed. RESULTS: Reconstruction was performed on 240 consecutive women (94 bilateral and 146 unilateral; 334 total reconstructions). Reconstruction timing was evenly split between immediate (n = 167) and delayed (n = 167). Autologous tissue (n = 192) was more common than tissue expander/implant reconstruction (n = 142), and the free deep inferior epigastric perforator was the most common free flap (n = 124). The authors found no difference in the complication incidence with autologous reconstruction, whether performed immediately or delayed. However, there was a significantly higher complication rate following immediate placement of a tissue expander when compared with delayed reconstruction (p = 0.008). Capsular contracture was a significantly more common late complication following immediate (40.4 percent) versus delayed (17.0 percent) reconstruction (p &lt; 0.001; odds ratio, 5.2; 95 percent confidence interval, 2.3 to 11.6). CONCLUSIONS: Autologous reconstruction can be performed immediately or delayed, with optimal aesthetic outcome and low flap loss risk. However, the overall complication and capsular contracture incidence following immediate tissue expander/implant reconstruction was much higher than when performed delayed. Thus, tissue expander placement at the time of mastectomy may not necessarily save the patient an extra operation and may compromise the final aesthetic outcome.</Abstract>
<BookTitle>Book1</BookTitle>
<Publisher>Publisher01, Boston</Publisher>
<Edition>1st</Edition>
<EditorList>
    <Editor>
        <LastName>Lewis</LastName>
        <ForeName>Philip M</ForeName>
        <Initials>PM</Initials>
    </Editor>
    <Editor>
        <LastName>Kiffer</LastName>
        <ForeName>Michael</ForeName>
        <Initials>M</Initials>
    </Editor>
</EditorList>
<Page>19-28</Page>
<Year>2008</Year>
<AuthorList>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Sullivan</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Stephen R</ForeName>
                    <Initials>SR</Initials>
                </Author>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Fletcher</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Derek R D</ForeName>
                    <Initials>DR</Initials>
                </Author>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Isom</LastName>
                    <ForeName>Casey D</ForeName>
                    <Initials>CD</Initials>
                </Author>
                <Author ValidYN="Y">
                    <LastName>Isik</LastName>
                    <ForeName>F Frank</ForeName>
                    <Initials>FF</Initials>
                </Author>
</AuthorList>
//
```

PaperTitle, Abstract, and Page, need to go into the Papers.txt file

PaperTitle, BookTitle, Edition, Publisher, and Year need to go into the Book.txt file

PaperTitle, all editor data LastName, ForeName, Initials need to go into the Editors.txt

PaperTitle, all author info LastName, ForeName, Initials need to go into the Authors.txt

// marks the end of an entry. All files need to be tab delimited. 
While I wouldn't turn down finished code, I am hoping for at least some ideas to put me in the right direction of at least the code to parse out one of the files (like Book.txt) I could most likely figure it out from there. Many thanks."

Comment: I would start by looking at using the Config::General module to handle the parsing and the Text::CSV_XS module for generating the output files.

Comment: It sounds like you need `XML::Twig`. Please show the file contents that would result from this data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this one:
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Cwd;

```
#Get Directory
my $dir = getcwd();

#Grep files from the directory
opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Couldn't open/read the $dir: $!";
my @AllFiles = grep(/\.txt$/i, readdir(DIR));
closedir(DIR);

#Check files are available 
if(scalar(@AllFiles) ne '')
{
    #Create Text Files as per Requirement
    open(PAP, ">$dir/Papers.txt") || die "Couldn't able to create the file: $!";
    open(BOOK, ">$dir/Book.txt") || die "Couldn't able to create the file: $!";
    open(EDT, ">$dir/Editors.txt") || die "Couldn't able to create the file: $!";
    open(AUT, ">$dir/Authors.txt") || die "Couldn't able to create the file: $!";
}
else {  die "File Not found...$dir\n"; } #Die if not found files
foreach my $input (@AllFiles)
{
    print "Processing file $input\n";
    open(IN, "$dir/$input") || die "Couldn't able to open the file: $!";
    local $/; $_=<IN>; my $tmp=$_;
    close(IN);
    #Loop from <PaperTitle> to // end slash
    while($tmp=~m/(<PaperTitle>((?:(?!\/\/).)*)\/\/)/gs)
    {
        my $LoopCnt = $1;
        my ($pptle) = $LoopCnt=~m/<PaperTitle>([^<>]*)<\/PaperTitle>/g;
        my ($abstr) = $LoopCnt=~m/<Abstract>([^<>]*)<\/Abstract>/gs;
        my ($pgrng) = $LoopCnt=~m/<Page>([^<>]*)<\/Page>/g;
        my ($bktle) = $LoopCnt=~m/<BookTitle>([^<>]*)<\/BookTitle>/g;
        my ($edtns) = $LoopCnt=~m/<Edition>([^<>]*)<\/Edition>/g;
        my ($publr) = $LoopCnt=~m/<Publisher>([^<>]*)<\/Publisher>/g;
        my ($years) = $LoopCnt=~m/<Year>([^<>]*)<\/Year>/g;

        my ($EditorNames, $AuthorNames) = "";
        $LoopCnt=~s#<EditorList>((?:(?!<\/EditorList>).)*)</EditorList>#
        my $edtList = $1; my @Edlines = split/\n/, $edtList;
        my $i ='1'; \#Editor Count to check
        foreach my $EdsngLine(@Edlines)
        {
            if($EdsngLine=~m/<LastName>([^<>]*)<\/LastName>/)
            {  $EditorNames .= $i."".$1."\t"; $i++; }
            elsif($EdsngLine=~m/<ForeName>([^<>]*)<\/ForeName>/)
            {  $EditorNames .= $1."\t"; }
            elsif($EdsngLine=~m/<Initials>([^<>]*)<\/Initials>/)
            {  $EditorNames .= $1."\t"; }
        }
        #esg;
        $LoopCnt=~s#<AuthorList>((?:(?!<\/AuthorList>).)*)</AuthorList>#
        my $autList = $1; my @Autlines = split/\n/, $autList;
        my $j ='1'; \#Author Count to check
        foreach my $AutsngLine(@Autlines)
        {
            if($AutsngLine=~m/<LastName>([^<>]*)<\/LastName>/)
            {  $AuthorNames .= $j."".$1."\t"; $j++; }
            elsif($AutsngLine=~m/<ForeName>([^<>]*)<\/ForeName>/)
            {  $AuthorNames .= $1."\t"; }
            elsif($AutsngLine=~m/<Initials>([^<>]*)<\/Initials>/)
            {  $AuthorNames .= $1."\t"; }
        }
        #esg;

        #Print the output in the crossponding text files
        print PAP "$pptle\t$abstr\t$pgrng\t//\n";
        print BOOK "$pptle\t$bktle\t$edtns\t$publr\t$years\t//\n";
        print EDT "$pptle\t$EditorNames//\n";
        print AUT "$pptle\t$AuthorNames//\n";
    }
}

print "Process Completed...\n";

#Don't forget to close the files
close(PAP);
close(BOOK);
close(EDT);
close(AUT);
#End
```

Comment: There is no excuse for parsing XML using regular expressions.

Comment: @Borodin: I would be interested in using XML modules. Could you please fulfill the code then I move further in my programs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin and ssr1012 for your help here. I should have specified one other thing. I will have to run this script on a number of files (ex: BC_Book, EC_Book, CC_Book, etc). 15 files all together. I would like to concatenate the data, or add to the file each time the script is compiled, but here the file is being created new each time. I should be able to track the code down myself, but I'm being lazy/bogged down by other aspects of this project. Additional help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This example should help you. It uses [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) as I suggested to extract the fields for the `Papers.txt` output file. The record separator is set to `"//\n"` so that an entire block of data is read in one go, and before the block is parsed it is wrapped in `<Paper>...</Paper>` tags to make it valid XML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;

open my $fh, '<', 'papers.txt';
local $/ = "//\n";

while (<$fh>) {
  $twig->parse("<Paper>\n$_\n</Paper>\n");
  my $root = $twig->root;
  say $root->field($_) for qw/ PaperTitle Abstract Page/;
  say '---';
}
```

**output**

```
True incidence of all complications following immediate and delayed breast reconstruction.
BACKGROUND: Improved self-image and psychological well-being after breast reconstruction are well documented. To determine methods that optimized results with minimal morbidity, the authors examined their results and complications based on reconstruction method and timing. METHODS: The authors reviewed all breast reconstructions after mastectomy for breast cancer performed under the supervision of a single surgeon over a 6-year period at a tertiary referral center. Reconstruction method and timing, patient characteristics, and complication rates were reviewed. RESULTS: Reconstruction was performed on 240 consecutive women (94 bilateral and 146 unilateral; 334 total reconstructions). Reconstruction timing was evenly split between immediate (n = 167) and delayed (n = 167). Autologous tissue (n = 192) was more common than tissue expander/implant reconstruction (n = 142), and the free deep inferior epigastric perforator was the most common free flap (n = 124). The authors found no difference in the complication incidence with autologous reconstruction, whether performed immediately or delayed. However, there was a significantly higher complication rate following immediate placement of a tissue expander when compared with delayed reconstruction (p = 0.008). Capsular contracture was a significantly more common late complication following immediate (40.4 percent) versus delayed (17.0 percent) reconstruction (p < 0.001; odds ratio, 5.2; 95 percent confidence interval, 2.3 to 11.6). CONCLUSIONS: Autologous reconstruction can be performed immediately or delayed, with optimal aesthetic outcome and low flap loss risk. However, the overall complication and capsular contracture incidence following immediate tissue expander/implant reconstruction was much higher than when performed delayed. Thus, tissue expander placement at the time of mastectomy may not necessarily save the patient an extra operation and may compromise the final aesthetic outcome.
19-28
---
```

Comment: Thank you @Borodin for your help here. This is still pretty far from where I could take the code to implement my own full program. Still I understand what you've done here, and I appreciate your help.